# Create React App not working : error @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.10.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module?

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm not sure why yarn create react app fails. The error message suggest `@typescript-eslint/esling-plugin version` is not compatible with the `node engine`. I've also tried yarn `cache clean --force` but doesn't work. I don't have a package.json to change the node engine as you can see on the terminal it gets deleted. Thank you

```
yarn v : 1.21.1
node v : 11.2.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **node** version:

> node v : 11.2.0

Error message:

> Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1"

Version `>=11.10.1` mean 11.10.1, 11.10.2, ..., 11.11.* ...
You have 10.2 which is less then 11.10

Upgrade **node**, or search another version of library which is compatible with your **node** version if any